# python: what's the point of adding`__dict__` to `__slots__`

Tags: python

The whole point of `__slots__` is to save space.

But I saw people add `__dict__` to it so that new attributes can be added. Isn't this defeating the goal of `__slots__`?

Comment: Just because you _can_ add `__dict__` to `__slots__` doesn't mean you should, or that there is any good reason to.

Comment: `__Slots__` and `__dict__` are different. You have got the basic concept right. This post might help you: <br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/python-slots Hope that helps :)

Comment: `__slots__` also creates descriptors that make attribute access faster. Having `__dict__` in `__slots__` will still create a dictionary and allow dynamic attributes, but accessing them will be (very) slightly faster. (Sorry for poking an old thread, I felt like the accepted answer was insufficient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you want `__dict__`, then just don't use `__slots__`.